# nodemailer failed to authenticate

Tags: authentication, smtp, nodemailer

I have two scripts, one just for testing sending email using my outlook.com personal account, which works fine. I then copied exactly same code to another script where it does something else (websocket communication with a server). Somehow nodemailer failed to auth in my 2nd script. I checked the nodemailer transporter object and auth info is populated and identical as what 1st script has.

Below is the working debug info that shows SMTP handshakes

```
[2023-06-29 14:52:16] DEBUG [5i7UT2eGg] S: 250-8BITMIME
[2023-06-29 14:52:16] DEBUG [5i7UT2eGg] S: 250-BINARYMIME
[2023-06-29 14:52:16] DEBUG [5i7UT2eGg] S: 250-CHUNKING
[2023-06-29 14:52:16] DEBUG [5i7UT2eGg] S: 250 SMTPUTF8
**[2023-06-29 14:52:16] DEBUG [5i7UT2eGg] SMTP handshake finished
[2023-06-29 14:52:16] DEBUG [5i7UT2eGg] C: AUTH LOGIN**
[2023-06-29 14:52:16] DEBUG [BTuSSj4Fag] S: 250-YT4PR01CA0038.outlook.office365.com Hello [99.228.44.71]
```

Below is the failing debug info

```
[2023-06-29 14:56:39] DEBUG [MljimETaxw] S: 250-BINARYMIME
[2023-06-29 14:56:39] DEBUG [MljimETaxw] S: 250-CHUNKING
[2023-06-29 14:56:39] DEBUG [MljimETaxw] S: 250 SMTPUTF8
[2023-06-29 14:56:39] DEBUG [MljimETaxw] SMTP handshake finished
**[2023-06-29 14:56:39] DEBUG [MljimETaxw] Closing connection to the server using "end"
[2023-06-29 14:56:39] ERROR Send Error: Missing credentials for "LOGIN"**
Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...
C:\AzureApps\test and demo\send email\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:790
            err = new Error(message);
                  ^

Error:** Missing credentials for "LOGIN"**
    at SMTPConnection._formatError (C:\AzureApps\test and demo\send email\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:790:19)
    at SMTPConnection.login (C:\AzureApps\test and demo\send email\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:444:38)
    at C:\AzureApps\test and demo\send email\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-transport\index.js:272:32
    at SMTPConnection.<anonymous> (C:\AzureApps\test and demo\send email\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:213:17)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:627:28)
    at SMTPConnection.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at SMTPConnection._actionEHLO (C:\AzureApps\test and demo\send email\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:1347:14)
    at SMTPConnection._processResponse (C:\AzureApps\test and demo\send email\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:969:20)
    at SMTPConnection._onData (C:\AzureApps\test and demo\send email\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:755:14)
    at SMTPConnection._onSocketData (C:\AzureApps\test and demo\send email\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:193:44) {
  code: 'EAUTH',
  command: 'API'
```

Interestingly, it doesn't error out until end of whole script. The transporter creation and sendMail command were successfully executed (as far as I can see from VS Code) but no email was sent/received. It seems that sendMail is only to schedule to send instead of send immediately. This is true in both my working script and non-working script - SMTP communications don't happen until end of script.

Any help is appreciated.

---